# According to Catholicism, was there a co-relation between the time of Transfiguration of Jesus and that of his Prayer at Gethsemane?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, prayer, transfiguration

We read in Luke 9:28-32 an account of  the Transfiguration of Jesus:

> Now about eight days after these sayings Jesus took with him Peter and John and James, and went up on the mountain to pray.   And while he was praying, the appearance of his face changed, and his clothes became dazzling white. Suddenly they saw two men, Moses and Elijah, talking to him. They appeared in glory and were speaking of his departure, which he was about to accomplish at Jerusalem. Now Peter and his companions were weighed down with sleep; but since they had stayed awake, they saw his glory and the two men who stood with him.

Luke is the only Evangelist who mentions that Peter and his companions were weighed down with sleep, suggesting that the Transfiguration took place late in the night. We also see Jesus praying at Gethsemane late in the night while  his disciples were fast asleep (Mtt 26:43). At the Transfiguration the apostles see him in sheer glory and power  while at Gethsemane, they see him totally human and helpless. That leads one to believe that Jesus had in fact chosen the timing of both his Transfiguration and  the Prayer at Gethsemane with a purpose.

My question therefore is: **According to Catholic Church, was there a co-relation between the time of Transfiguration of Jesus and that of his Prayer at Gethsemane?**